# How do you set an entry in a numpy array to 0 or None if the entries are structured arrays themselves?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list of objects that are structured arrays, for example something like this:

```
a = np.array([('Rex', 9, 81.0), ('Fido', 3, 27.0)], dtype=[('name', 'U10'), ('age', 'i4'), ('weight', 'f4')])
b = np.array([('Dog3', 9, 81.0), ('Dog4', 3, 27.0)], dtype=[('name', 'U10'), ('age', 'i4'), ('weight', 'f4')])
c = np.array([('Dog5', 9, 81.0), ('Dog6', 3, 27.0)], dtype=[('name', 'U10'), ('age', 'i4'), ('weight', 'f4')])

lst = [a, b, c]
```

Now I need this list to be a numpy array itself because I need to use `numpy.where()` on it and this does not work otherwise.

```
lst = np.array(lst)
```

So then I do something like this:

```
ID = np.where(lst == c)
lst[ID] = 0 or rather lst[ID] = None
```

But instead of what I would like to get, i.e.

```
>>>lst
array([a, b, 0/None], dtype=...)
```

I either get this:

```
>>>lst
array([a, b, [('0', 0,  0.), ('0', 0,  0.)]], dtype=...)
```

Or it does not work at all:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

How can I acomplish this? Do I have to convert `lst` back into a list fist?

Comment: by running your code im able to get your expected result. would it be a version problem?

Comment: What happens with `c[:]=0` or `np.zeros(1, dtype=c.dtype)`?  Don't confuse this compound dtype with object dtype.

Comment: The kind of substitution works in the original `lst`, but not with the array, where all elements have to have that shared compound dtype.  What you get is a valid version of `c` with all fields set to 0 (or '0' for the string field).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you so much guys for taking the time to try and solve my problem! I am new to this so I haven't really wrapped my head around what a structured array really is and how to use it properly. I have found a better way now by simply using `np.delete(lst, ID)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a simpler array, and try to set some values:

```
In [14]: dt = np.dtype([('foo','U10'),('bar',int)])                             
In [16]: arr = np.zeros(3, dtype=dt)                                            
In [17]: arr                                                                    
Out[17]: array([('', 0), ('', 0), ('', 0)], dtype=[('foo', '<U10'), ('bar', '<i8')])
In [18]: arr[1]                                                                 
Out[18]: ('', 0)
In [19]: arr[1] = 12                                                            
In [20]: arr                                                                    
Out[20]: 
array([('',  0), ('12', 12), ('',  0)],
      dtype=[('foo', '<U10'), ('bar', '<i8')])
```

note the mix of string '12' and integer 12.

Set with a tuple, one value for each field:

```
In [21]: arr[2] = ('dog',23)
```

set with a `None` fails because it can't convert `None` to integer, as required by the 2nd field.

```
In [22]: arr[0] = None                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-2f7a4c897706> in <module>
----> 1 arr[0] = None

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
In [23]: arr                                                                    
Out[23]: 
array([('None',  0), ('12', 12), ('dog', 23)],
      dtype=[('foo', '<U10'), ('bar', '<i8')])
```

Actually it did manage to set the string field.

`arr` is an array, where each element must have the same `dtype`.

An array with `object` dtype behaves a lot more like a list.  While occasionally useful, it shouldn't be used as a substitute for lists.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It helped me find a solution.